# Train a Cascade Object Detector in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to train a cascade object detector in MATLAB using the built in functionality from the Computer Vision Toolbox.

I’ve taken 500 photo’s of the sole of my shoe.  Every photo is taken from the same angle, so there is very little shifting in rotation and scaling from all of the images.

For the negative images I am using 500 photo’s of the background that is behind the shoe in the positive images.

The reason I am using the background as the negative photo’s is to train the classifier to overlook the background.

After I train the cascade classifier with these positive and negative images and apply it to another image of my shoe (taken from the same angle as one of the positive images) the detector does not detect the shoe!

What am I doing wrong?

Here are two of the photo's I am using for the negative and positive image (with bounding box shown).

[image]

[image]

---

Here is the code I have written that performs this task:

```
% Load Positive Images with Bounding Boxes from the "Training Image Labeler App"
data = positiveInstances; 

% Load Negative Images 
negativeFolder = fullfile('C:\shoes\neg'); 

% Train Detector 
trainCascadeObjectDetector('detector.xml', data, negativeFolder); 

% Use Detector 
detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('detector.xml'); 
test_image = imread('C:\shoes\test.jpg'); 
bbox = step(detector, test_image); 
detectedImage = insertObjectAnnotation(test_image, 'rectangle', ... 
                                       bbox,       'shoe'); 

figure; 
imshow(detectedImage)
```

Comment: What feature detectors are you using? What cascade detector are you using? Also, showing some code would go along way. If you just want to detect that shoe by itself then what you're doing will work. It may be a problem with something in your code than your overall method.

Comment: Here is the code I am using: % Load Positive
data  = positiveInstances;
  
% Load Negative Images
negativeFolder = fullfile('C:\shoes\neg');
 
% Train Detector
trainCascadeObjectDetector('detector.xml', data, negativeFolder);
  
% Use Detector
detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('detector.xml');
test_image = imread('C:\shoes\test.jpg');
bbox = step(detector, test_image);
detectedImage = insertObjectAnnotation(test_image, 'rectangle', ...
                                       bbox,       'shoe');
figure; imshow(detectedImage);

Comment: Please edit your question to include this code.  Placing code in comments that is more than a couple of lines doesn't look very nice.

Comment: I'm very sorry about my code above.  I couldn't get it in the proper format fast enough to edit it.  Can someone fix it?  As for the code, I am using the built in training app to put the bounding boxes around each shoe, and saving the data in positiveInstances, which I use in the first line of the code.

Comment: I will place an edit.

Comment: Done.  Once the edit is approved, I'll help you out!

Comment: Okay, so I am now trying to simplify the problem even further. I now have the camera fixed in one location (I was taking the pictures by holding the camera in my hands previously). I have taken 1000 photo's of a coin without moving the coin. I have taken 2000 photo's of the background as the negative images. I feed these positive and negative image sets into the trainCascadeObjectDetector function and try to use the resulting CascadeObjectDetector object on an image of the coin that is in the same location as in the training set.  Still the coin is not being found! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My gut feeling is that your positive images are including a lot of extraneous information.  Try taking pictures of your shoes without any unnecessary background.  When you're training your classifier, the background features where your shoe is located will also count in your positive example training.  The code to me looks pretty standard when you want to use the detector out of the box.

Comment: Can you post the diagnostic output of trainCascadeObjectDetector?

Comment: @user8919, Can you share the data?